# How to hide a Published Tab on Author's Wordpress Dashboard?

Tags: wordpress, dashboard, author

I have several Authors on WordPress site and when an Author login and see his Dashboard, he see a Published tab that consists of all published posts by other Authors.

I need a script to hide that Published tab on Dashboard. Or better if the script only hide other Authors' published posts without hiding Published tab itself.

Please see the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyQEY.png

Thank you

Newbee

Answer (score 0):

the following code will remove the Publish Tab from the Post List. This works in Post List only.

```
add_action( 'views_edit-book-review', 'remove_edit_post_views' );
function remove_edit_post_views( $views ) {

    unset($views['publish']);
    return $views;

}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you  

Sorry not to clear in advance. I need to hide that Tabs on custom post ‘book-review’. So I modify the code:  

`function remove_views( $views ) {  
    unset($views['all']);  
    unset($views['publish']);  
    unset($views['trash']);  
  
    return $views;  
}  
  
add_action( 'views_edit-book-review',  'remove_views' );  `  
  
But the code is not working. The tabs (All, Published) are still displayed

Comment: that can be done also, before you unset you need to check the post type. let me change the answer

Comment: Please check the answer  `views_edit-book-review` is your hook for custom post type

Comment: Yes, book-review is the slug for that custom post.

Comment: Just copy and paste the code and hope that works for you.

Comment: Please check your post type slug. I tried at my end and it is working fine with my post type